# Android Png overlay problems

Tags: android, google-maps, png, overlay

```
public PNGOverlay(Bitmap original, GeoPoint topLeftGeoPoint, GeoPoint bottomRightGeoPoint) {
    this.original = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), true);


    ...
    topGeoPoint = topLeftGeoPoint;
    bottomGeoPoint = bottomRightGeoPoint;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        Point leftTop = new Point();
        Point rightTop = new Point();
        Point rightBottom = new Point();
        Point leftBottom = new Point();

        projection.toPixels(topGeoPoint, leftTop);
        projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint(topGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), bottomGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()), rightTop);
        projection.toPixels(bottomGeoPoint, rightBottom);
        projection.toPixels(new GeoPoint(bottomGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), topGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()), leftBottom);

        ....

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(original, null, new Rect(leftTop.x, leftTop.y, rightBottom.x, rightBottom.y), paint);

       ....
}
```

I have a problem with this code. When I draw the png on the mapView, the png image is showed over the compass and over the GPS position indicatior? Any idea?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you mean above (upper in the screen) or over (sobreposition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question is difficult to guess what is exactly your problem, but if you mean that the PNG is being drawn over the other overlays and you want it to be under them, you can solve it by adding the PNG overlay first to the mapview.

MapView calls the draw method from each overlay by the order that you add them:

```
mapview.getoverlays().add(overlay1);
mapview.getoverlays().add(overlay2);
```

This results in overlay2 being drawn over overlay1.

```
mapview.getoverlays().add(overlay2);
mapview.getoverlays().add(overlay1);
```

This results in overlay1 being drawn over overlay2.

good luck.

Comment: Hi Luis, the problem is with the compass layer of the google map. Take a look to this images http://212.92.53.23/photo.JPG

Comment: Hi Ernesto, you can solve the problem with the solution I'm showing above. Just add the overlay that draw the PNG image before any other overlayer and it will be the first being drawn. The other overlays will then be drawn over the image. Let me know if you need more details how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I thought that the compass layer is included by default. I change the mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay) order and "bingo".

Comment: Hi Ernest0, when you have a minute accept the answer, so everyone knows it's solved without reading all the comments.